# How to change specific times in as.POSIXct format to NA?

Tags: r, posixct

I have in my dataset dates and times. They are in `as.POSIXct` format.
I want to change dates/times to `NA`, if the time is `00:00:00`.

The name of the column is for example `Data$Operation`

- This date/time is correct: `2015-01-01 11:45:00`
- This date/time has to change to `NA`: `2015-01-02 00:00:00`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using x as test data replace any component for which the format using %T is as shown.

```
# test input
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 11:45:00", "2015-01-01 00:00:00"))

replace(x, format(x, "%T") == "00:00:00", NA)
## [1] "2015-01-01 11:45:00 EST" NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was where I was looking for!